# li should stay right

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I've a list with three list items with different widths. If the first li ist larger then the other, the list items floating left (screenshot).

[image]

Is there a way to prevent it?

My HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-button">
        <nav class="main-nav" style="width:400px">
        </nav>
    </li>
    <li style="width:200px"><a href="#"></a><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>
    <li style="width:200px"><a href="#"></a><i class="fa fa-key"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They aren't floated (presumably anyway, that HTML (which is awful: Links with no link text and italic text with no text next to them) won't produce that result without CSS which you haven't shared with us), they are just left aligned. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: The last two elements should stay right.

Comment: CSS provides many ways to align things to the right, which is appropriate depends on things like the display property of the element you want to align … and the screenshot implies you've changed that from the default, but we don't know what to. Aligning things is pretty basic stuff, you should be able to find the solution with a little bit of work with a search engine.

Comment: This needs complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need. A [working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ax2fL6th/) (please add a working fiddle in your question in the future, so we have something to work with).

What I did was give your `ul` a set width, with the biggest `li` filling 100% of the `ul` and the other ones filling 50% of the `ul`. (since this was also what happened in your example, 400px and 200px). Giving those blocks a `float: right;` would put them in one line. Giving a `margin-left` fixed this problem (since 50% + 50% + 10px + 10px > 100% width).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-button">
        <nav class="main-nav" style="width:400px;">
        </nav>
    </li>
    <li ><a href="#"></a><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>
    <li ><a href="#"></a><i class="fa fa-key"></i></li>
</ul>
```

I have removed all in-line CSS from the HTML, you should also do this in your project.

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

li {
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.nav-button {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

li:not(.nav-button) {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```